# Laravel 5.3 Learning if statements

Tags: php, laravel

I'm just practicing at the moment and just wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.

Why would this return a blank page if no results are found, if i put an item in the database it returns the item.

```
Route::get('/read', function (){

    $posts = Post::all();

    if(empty($posts)) {
        echo "No Posts Exist";

    } else {

        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            return $post->title;
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Try returning the string instead of echoing it.

Comment: just tried that and no luck :( just a blank white page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all() returns a collection. Many ways to skin this cat, but I think you're looking for isEmpty()

```
if($posts->isEmpty()) { ... }
```

Other options would be ->count() === 0. Collection methods are listed here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections

Comment: If only there was a trait that could be used to make empty() behave on it like an array.